# PHP - Extract attributes and text from string for each <div>

Tags: php, arrays, attributes, extract

I have a string `$value` which looks like that:

```
'<div id='1' data-AAA='something1' data-BBB='something2'>My</div><div id='5' data-AAA='something5' data-BBB='something6'>Web</div>
...'
```

In PHP, I would like for each `<div>`, extract all data attributes (here `id`, `data-AAA` and `data-BBB`) and also the text, and then put them into an array like that:

```
Array
  [0]
     ID => 1
     data-AAA => something1
     data-BBB => something2
     text => My
  [1]
     ID => 5
     data-AAA => something5
     data-BBB => something6
     text => Web
```

Is it possible to extract all those informations from a string with a loop ? being debutant, I have no idea how to do that for a string...

**EDIT 1**

thanks to the DOM doc (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) given in answers, I tried this and that works !

```
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($value);
        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $ST) {
            $valueID = $ST->getAttribute('id');
            $valueDataTimeStart = $ST->getAttribute('data-AAA');
            $valueDataTimeStart = $ST->getAttribute('data-BBB');
            $valueDataTimeEnd = $ST->getAttribute('id');
            var_dump($valueID);
            var_dump($valueDataTimeStart);
            var_dump($valueDataTimeEnd);
        }die;
```

Comment: [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: DAM DAM [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)! (<- I think you are looking for this :)

Comment: Thanks to you ! This is what I seached :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($l_sContent);
$l_aDiv = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div");
foreach ($l_aDiv as $l_aOneDiv) {
 // search attributes on $l_aOneDiv
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, I tried that 5 minutes ago and it works :)